# How can I filter my json object by id in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json

Hi this is my first question.

I want to filter my json object by id

This is the JSON file code I pasted below:

```
[
  {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Class 1",
  "sub_informations": [
     {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "John",
     "sex": "male",
     "user": 1,
     },
     {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "Agatha",
     "sex": "female",
     "user": 1,
     }
    ]
  },
  {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Class 2",
  "sub_informations": [
    {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Ben",
    "sex": "male",
    "user": 2,
    }
  ]
}
]
```

what I want is to be able to put the sub_informations elements in the li tag according to the id.

That is, I want to bring the name and gender information of class 1 to my first li tag, and the name and gender information of class 2 to my second li tag.

How can i write this in code?

```
import React from 'react'
import user from 'api/users.json'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
       setTimeout(() =>setUsers (user),1000)
  return (
    <>
        {users.map((index, i) => {
        <ul>
               
                <li>{index.id[1]}</li>
                <li>{index.id[2]}</li>
  
        </ul>
        })}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understood what you want to do correctly but I believe what you need to do is just simply map within the map again over `sub_informations`. So that you have a nested list.

Comment: `users.filter(...)`?

Comment: I want to map the first class's sub_information in my first li tag and the second class's sub_information in my second li tag. How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

i understand you can make list by id. I belive you can do so like this :

```
 return (
<>
    {users.map((index, i) => {
    <ul>   
        {
            index.id === 1 &&
            (
                <>
                    <h1>{index.name}</h1>
                    {
                        index.sub_informations.map((sub, ind) => {
                            <li>
                                {sub.name + " " + sub.sex}
                            </li>
                        })
                    }
                </>
            )
        }   
        {
            index.id === 2 &&
            (
                <>
                    <h1>{index.name}</h1>
                    {
                        index.sub_informations.map((sub, ind) => {
                            <li>
                                {sub.name + " " + sub.sex}
                            </li>
                        })
                    }
                </>
            )
        }     
    </ul>
    })}
</>
```

If this doesn't what you want to do , please tell us more information for we can help you.

Comment: nothing is printed on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that OP needs to list down the `sub_information` under a list for each `user` entry/object, the below solution may achieve this assumed objective:

**Code Snippet**

```js
const Thingy = ({users, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <div>
     {users.map(u => (
      <ul>
        {u.name}
        {u["sub_informations"].map(si => (
          <li>
            {si.id} {si.name} {si.sex}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
     ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const rawData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Class 1",
    "sub_informations": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "sex": "male",
        "user": 1,
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Agatha",
        "sex": "female",
        "user": 1,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Class 2",
    "sub_informations": [{
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Ben",
      "sex": "male",
      "user": 2,
    }]
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    DEMO
    <Thingy users={rawData}/>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```html
<div id="rd" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation**

- Iterate over `users` array
- For each user, iterate over `sub_information` array
- For each element, render it's props (such as `id`, `name`, `sex`, etc)

OP needs to clarify if this is not what they desired to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The following results in a nested list by using `map` twice to iterate once of the `users` and once over the `sub_informations`.

```js
const myUsers = [
  {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Class 1",
  "sub_informations": [
     {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "John",
     "sex": "male",
     "user": 1,
     },
     {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "Agatha",
     "sex": "female",
     "user": 1,
     }
    ]
  },
  {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Class 2",
  "sub_informations": [
    {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Ben",
    "sex": "male",
    "user": 2,
    }
  ]
}
];

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState(myUsers);

  return (
    <ul>
      {users.map((user) => {
        if (!user.sub_informations) {
          return (
            <li>
              {user.id} || {user.name}
            </li>
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <React.Fragment>
              <li>
                {user.id} || {user.name}
              </li>
              <ul>
                {user.sub_informations.map((info) => (
                  <li>
                    {info.id} || {info.name} || {info.sex} || {info.user}
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        }
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}



ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

> Note: Some slight [adjustments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support) to your code where necessary to be able to put this in a snippet.